# How can I draw over a full screen application

Tags: c#, drawing

I want to make a program to display information while I'm in another full screen application.
Something like: show what song is playing(from Winamp) while in Starcraft II.

How would I got about doing that?

Comment: For starters, you'll probably need to slap down a Pylon near where you hope to display the winamp. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would start by creating a new window with the topmost flag set. I think that will do what you want. You might have to manually move that window to the top of the topmost z order with a call to SetWindowPos. (SetWindowPos is a win32 call, but you can pInvoke it from C# if needed.)

Comment: Then set it to catch specific events (like when winamp starts another song), if they are available, and then answer to them appropriately, like showing itself with the name of the song, then fading away/hiding itself.